# Не работает роутинг в angular 13

Tags: angular

Ребята, создал два коппонента, прописал пути, в html прописал 
но когда нажимаешь на ссылку локалхост в консоли попадаю на пустую страничку белую, ошибок в консоли нет.

app-routing.module.ts

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
 import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
 import {RegistrationComponent} from './registration/registration.component';


const routes: Routes = [

 {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
 {path: '**', component: RegistrationComponent},
             ];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
     })
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './registration/registration.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {  HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RegistrationComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

registration.component.html

```
<p>registration works!</p>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` в `app.component.html`.